# Java: short circuit evaluation in boolean expressions

Tags: java

I was wondering what happens if a variable is null, and within a boolean condition, a method is called on that null variable. will it throw an exception?

```
MyObj chair = null
chair = getSpecialMethod();
if(chair != null && chair.size()){
  ....
}
```

What happens to the case if `chair` is null, will an exception be  thrown, even though it is checked for a null value *before* `chair.size()` is called?

Comment: Did you try for yourself, and see what happens?

Comment: This question is not titled appropriately; better would be "Java: short circuit evaluation in boolean expressions"

Comment: Is it really more efficient to ask this question on the Internet, and wait possibly forever for a possibly incorrect answer, or for several mutually irreconcilable answers, than it is to try it for yourself? or look up the relevant language specification?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Java evaluate remaining conditions after boolean result is known?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352139/does-java-evaluate-remaining-conditions-after-boolean-result-is-known)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the second part of the condition is not evaluated as the first is `false`, when `chair` is `null`, so a `NullPointerException` is not thrown.

From section [15.23. Conditional-And Operator &&](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.23) in the Java Language Specification:

> The conditional-and operator && is like & (§15.22.2), but evaluates its right-hand operand only if the value of its left-hand operand is true.

Comment: +1 for quoting Java Language Specification! i have been coding Java for few years and sometimes get thrown by fundamental stuff like this

Answer (score 1):

In this case it does not matter, `&&` is a short circuit operator and thus if `chair` is null than `chair.size()` will not run. If you did call a method on a null reference however it would throw a `NullPointerException`

Comment: so no exception will be thrown right?

Comment: Not in this case but if you did call a method on a null reference it would throw

Comment: @bouncingHippo What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Since you used `&&`, you are fine. It does not proceed if it encounters a false condition. If you had used `&`, then both the conditions would have been checked for and you would get a `NullPointerException`.