# Why am I getting an IndexOutOfBounds error when merging two arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception, array-merge

I have written code to merge two sorted arrays in Java.

```
public class MergeSortedArrays {
    public static int[] my_array     = {3, 4, 6, 10, 11, 15};
    public  static int[] alices_array = {1, 5, 8, 12, 14, 19};
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int length = my_array.length + alices_array.length;

        int[] new_array = new int[length];
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int count = 0;

        while (count < length) {

            if(my_array[i] < alices_array[j] ) {
                new_array[count] = my_array[i];
                i++;
            } else {
                new_array[count] = alices_array[j];
                j++;
            }

            count++;
        }
        for(int k=0;k<length;k++) {
            System.out.println(new_array[k]);
        }
    }

}
```

But I am getting this error-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
    at MergeSortedArrays.main(MergeSortedArrays.java:15)
```

One array is exhausted before merging is completed. How can I handle this case?

Comment: Your debugger is well-equipped to help you. If you're desperate to get this working then put all the elements into a TreeSet and read back the contents.

Comment: Yes I used a debugger  . One array is exhausted before merging is completed. How can I handle this case?

Comment: length returns 6 but your index starts at 0

Comment: You need to check if `i < my_array.length` and `j < alices_array.length`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't check if `my_array[i] < alices_array[j]` if you're past the end of `my_array`. So ensure that `i` is valid; if it's not, add an element from `j`. Similarly, you don't want to check `j` if it's past the end of that array. So, use this check instead of your previous if statement:

```
if(j >= alices_array.length || 
       (i < my_array.length && my_array[i] < alices_array[j] )) {
```

The reason it doesn't attempt to evaluate `my_array[i]` is because Java doesn't need to evaluate the second half of an `&&` expression if the first half is false. See [Does Java evaluate remaining conditions after boolean result is known?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6352139/1768232)

---

This answer will help you to solve **this** problem, but you should really read this article for getting better at programming:

- [**How to debug small programs**](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that when one array is done, you should only consider the other one:

```
while (count < length) {
    if (i == my_array.length) {
        new_array[count] = alices_array[j];
        j++;
    } else if (j == alices_array.length) {
        new_array[count] = my_array[i];
        i++;
    } else {
        if(my_array[i] < alices_array[j] ) {
            new_array[count] = my_array[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            new_array[count] = alices_array[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
    count++;
}
```

Comment: There's no need to copy the other array by hand once one array is exhausted. Use `System.arraycopy` (or its wrappers in `Arrays`) which is implemented in native code and way more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You must check the range of `i` and `j` in case the reach the end.

```
        if (i < my_array.length) {
            if (j < alices_array.length) {
                if (my_array[i] < alices_array[j]) {
                    new_array[count] = my_array[i];
                    i++;
                } else {
                    new_array[count] = alices_array[j];
                    j++;
                }

            } else {
                new_array[count] = my_array[i];
                i++;
            }
        } else {
            if (j < alices_array.length) {
                new_array[count] = alices_array[j];
                i++;
            }
        }
```